# Why there are so many controllers between user defined cell's UITextField and the cell view

Tags: iphone, superview

I'd like to get parent view of UITextField on my user defined cell.
What I've tried is just call superview method and it returns UIView, not a my cell view.
So I invoked superview several times.

UITextField -> UIView -> UITableViewCellContentView -> MyCellView

There're two more unexpected view. What are those and WHY?

add desc.) I've made my own cell and there's an UITextField.

Comment: The UIView inside UITableViewCellContentView is created by your app (possibly by Interface Builder). The content view corresponds to the UITableViewCell.contentView property; it's there to assist in proper layout when your cell has an accessory view or editing control.

Answer (score 0):

A UITableViewCell have a contentView where the custom view s are added. 
you can run a loop until you get the MyCellView

```
View view = textView.superView;
while( ![view isKindOfClass: [MyCellView class]]){
  view = view.superView;
}

// now you get the view as MyCellView
```